# Hybris: User action analysis feasibility

Tags: seo, sap-commerce-cloud

Is it feasible in hybris to analysis and store what the user/end customer is upto in the page? For example: is it feasible to just collect a report of what the user has clicked in the page and what the user is viewing?

All i need is a report of user actions. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably feasible but likely a bad idea. An Ecommerce platform should be real responsive to well... sales. All that extra user data in your database system is going to bring it to a crawl.

That said:
The reporting module could probably be extended to do this. I would siphon the data collected off to a separate reporting database.

Whats "better":
Using Google Analytics with the B2C Accelerator.

Whats "best":
Something like Adobe's Sitecatalyst. Generally if you can afford hybris, you can likely afford Sitecataylst.